# How to import an array into a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need some help with the code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var opcao = new Array (
            document.getElementById("cred_form_1864_1_wpcf-pde_Pesquisas_descontinuadas"),
            document.getElementById("cred_form_1864_1_wpcf-pnps_Pesquisas_nao_patenteaveis-sigilosas")
        );

        function check1(){
            if (opcao[0].checked == true){
                for (var i = 0; i < opcao.length; i++){
                    if (i != 0){
                        opcao[i].checked = false;
                        opcao[i].disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function check2(){
            if (opcao[1].checked == true){
                for (var i = 0; i < opcao.length; i++){
                    if (i != 1){
                        opcao[i].checked = false;
                        opcao[i].disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I need to call the array 'opcao' within the functions 'check1 ()' and 'check2 ()'. How can I do this?

====================

I tried the suggestion of Mishik did not work. What I need is that the functions 'check1 ()' and 'check2 ()' to access the same array 'opcao'.
If I write the array within each function the code works perfectly. But how are the same values ​​I would have to repeat the same array for each function created.

Comment: What do you mean by "call"?

Comment: Why do you use such short id's ? are you mixing JS programming with typing exercise ? ;)

Comment: Why nou use radio-buttons?

Comment: A fiddle would be useful

Comment: I guess you're "calling" i.e. referring to the global `opcao` correctly, what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Soon People will be explaining what the element is in their `id` 's like this `<div id="header-banner-shows-visitors-of-latest-deals-in-september-this-year---bye"> <img src="..."/> </div>`

Answer (score 2):

If your code is executed before the page is loaded, then `opcao` array will not actually contain required elements.

You need to wrap your code in `window.onload`, so that by the time script is executed all the required elements will be available in the `document`.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var opcao = new Array (
        document.getElementById("cred_form_1864_1_wpcf-pde_Pesquisas_descontinuadas"),
        document.getElementById("cred_form_1864_1_wpcf-pnps_Pesquisas_nao_patenteaveis-sigilosas")
    );

    function check1(){
        if (opcao[0].checked == true){
            for (var i = 0; i < opcao.length; i++){
                if (i != 0){
                    opcao[i].checked = false;
                    opcao[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function check2(){
        if (opcao[1].checked == true){
            for (var i = 0; i < opcao.length; i++){
                if (i != 1){
                    opcao[i].checked = false;
                    opcao[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe merely placing the script tag at the bottom would be sufficient in the OP's case. Nevertheless, this is a more fool-proof solution.